# Controller not recognizing installed Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, smartercsv

Okay, I know this is a bit of a simple question, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have installed the SmarterCSV gem in my Rails 4 app and am trying to use it in my controller like so:

```
SmarterCSV.process("/files/csv_file.csv")
```

I can do this exact process in the rails console for this app, but I cannot seem to get it to work in my controller. Every time I just get the Rails Dead Screen saying `uninitialized constant MyController::SmarterCSV`. I have tried adding the line

```
require 'smarter_csv'
```

But that also breaks to the Rails Dead Screen with the error `cannot load such file -- smarter_csv`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Im not entirely sure what I can do...

Comment: Did you include it in the gem file?

Comment: Yup lol. It's in the gem file, it bundled, all good there. I can use it in console without needing to require it

Comment: Did you try by simply using `::SmarterCSV` instead?

Comment: Still uninitialized constant

Comment: make sure to add smarter_csv to your Gemfile!

Answer (score 0):

you can try `require 'smarter_csv/smarter_csv'` as this is the path of the file in the gem https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv/blob/master/lib/smarter_csv/smarter_csv.rb

Comment: Same LoadError as before

Comment: Did you use `require: false` while adding the gem in your `Gemfile` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to restart your application after `bundle install`